# Azure pipelines not loading in JIRA

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, jira-plugin

Been facing this for a few days already. I wonder if there's anyone else having this kind of issue.
I go to My Apps in JIRA and select "Azure Pipelines for JIRA" then click on "Get Started" (I had already configured this once so it worked before) and get the following error:
[Error and console from JIRA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFNp1.png)

It mentions deprecated JS, cookies, and a server 500 error. Not sure what needs to be done here.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the answer, you could check the update1, if the issue is fixed, I will share it here.

Comment: It is not yet fixed. As states in the Azure DevOps Dev Community it will take at least a couple more weeks.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this issue and try to install the plugin via a new account again, I will get the 500 issue.

I have report this issue in the [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-jira/issues/41) and [Azure DevOps Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cannot-install-azure-pipelines-for-jira-in-the-jir/1388613), you could follow these links to get the latest news.

Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

**Update1**

Produce team response:

> We have run into additional issues, and would need a couple more weeks. I am working on it to get the fix in place as soon as possible.